# JAX-WS approach for IRS AIR - TPE1105 Error

Tags: irs

I have generated SOAP Message for IRS AIR Webservice through Java as well as SOAP UI. Both of them throwing same TPE1105 Error. I have tried validating letter by letter by searching for the error in StackOverflow and approached AIR Mail Box team too, but couldn't make it through. Can someone who ever made through this suggest me here if i am missing anything.
Mail Box team mentioned that : There is a  “Content is not allowed in prolog” error in their server logs. I have verified both Manifest and payload XMLs with HEX editor and I dont see any special characters causing BOM.

***Suggestion from AIR Team to resolve issue was:***

- Ensure there are no blank lines in the HTTP headers and only one blank line after the last HTTP headers  --> I dont see any extra blank lines other than MIME Boundary  seperation
- Ensure the Content-Type in the HTTP headers define the message as Multi-part per the AIR Submission Composition and Reference Guide, Section 10.3 --> HTTP Headers already has Multipart
- Ensure there are no hidden/special characters in the prolog of the SOAP envelope other than the XML version tag () --> There is no BOM ,I have verified both XMLs in HEX editor.

Still TPE1105 Error Persists

```
------=_Part_1_417037542.1463661950204
Accept-Charset:UTF-8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Content-Encoding:gzip
SOAPAction:BulkRequestTransmitter
MIME-Version:1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit
Content-Type:multipart/related;type=application/xop+xml;start=<root.message@cxf.apache.org>; start-info=text/xml;


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:urn="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0" xmlns:urn1="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common" xmlns:urn2="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acabusinessheader" xmlns:urn3="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acasecurityheader" xmlns:urn4="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:irsacabulkrequesttransmitter" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
<ds:Signature Id="SIG-448A38CF540948AEB5CC3FB2BE5A8EF9">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#WithComments"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<ds:Reference URI="#TS-2C362C7FC2DE2D497414636619501241">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
<InclusiveNamespaces xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="wsse wsa ds soap urn urn1 urn2 urn3 urn4"/>
</ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>ZmVvaHY1ibehWM=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference URI="#id-A4BFA88D4EED4410B5C4CC1EB850E576">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
<InclusiveNamespaces xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="wsa ds soap urn1 urn2 urn3 urn4 wsu"/>
</ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>Removed</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference URI="#id-FBA20BF181754306AAEF7C0E86D921CF">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
<InclusiveNamespaces xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="wsa ds soap urn urn1 urn3 urn4 wsu"/>
</ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>Removed</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>RemoveSigned Value</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-7DC2B854399F4264949A4FC8FF93B86C">
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-2AF22A9BE69747D392A768AC99E7EEF3">
<wsse:KeyIdentifier EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">MIIGGTCCBQGgAwIBAx7hj7N1m21NBFhMpco+vlQ=</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
</wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-2C362C7FC2DE2D497414636619501241">
<wsu:Created>2016-05-19T12:45:50Z</wsu:Created>
<wsu:Expires>2016-05-19T12:54:10Z</wsu:Expires>
</wsu:Timestamp>
</wsse:Security>
<urn:ACATransmitterManifestReqDtl wsu:Id="id-A4BFA88D4EED4410B5C4CC1EB850E576">
<urn:PaymentYr>2015</urn:PaymentYr>
<urn:PriorYearDataInd>0</urn:PriorYearDataInd>
<urn1:EIN>3434343</urn1:EIN>
<urn:TransmissionTypeCd>O</urn:TransmissionTypeCd>
<urn:TestFileCd>T</urn:TestFileCd>
<urn:TransmitterNameGrp>
<urn:BusinessNameLine1Txt>Stone</urn:BusinessNameLine1Txt>
</urn:TransmitterNameGrp>
<urn:CompanyInformationGrp>
<urn:CompanyNm>Hidetestone</urn:CompanyNm>
<urn:MailingAddressGrp>
<urn:USAddressGrp>
<urn:AddressLine1Txt>44 Older Lane Suite 312</urn:AddressLine1Txt>
<urn1:CityNm>New York</urn1:CityNm>
<urn:USStateCd>GA</urn:USStateCd>
<urn1:USZIPCd>34343</urn1:USZIPCd>
</urn:USAddressGrp>
</urn:MailingAddressGrp>
<urn:ContactNameGrp>
<urn:PersonFirstNm>Tharba</urn:PersonFirstNm>
<urn:PersonLastNm>Bengan</urn:PersonLastNm>
</urn:ContactNameGrp>
<urn:ContactPhoneNum>345345345</urn:ContactPhoneNum>
</urn:CompanyInformationGrp>
<urn:VendorInformationGrp>
<urn:VendorCd>I</urn:VendorCd>
<urn:ContactNameGrp>
<urn:PersonFirstNm>Tharba</urn:PersonFirstNm>
<urn:PersonLastNm>Bengan</urn:PersonLastNm>
</urn:ContactNameGrp>
<urn:ContactPhoneNum>3434343434</urn:ContactPhoneNum>
</urn:VendorInformationGrp>
<urn:TotalPayeeRecordCnt>2</urn:TotalPayeeRecordCnt>
<urn:TotalPayerRecordCnt>1</urn:TotalPayerRecordCnt>
<urn:SoftwareId>15A0000945</urn:SoftwareId>
<urn:FormTypeCd>1094/1095B</urn:FormTypeCd>
<urn1:BinaryFormatCd>application/xml</urn1:BinaryFormatCd>
<urn1:ChecksumAugmentationNum>4072b0f706a4591df6d7d8ba4e02c4e5</urn1:ChecksumAugmentationNum>
<urn1:AttachmentByteSizeNum>7277</urn1:AttachmentByteSizeNum>
<urn:DocumentSystemFileNm>1094B_Request_BB31Q_20160513T090758000Z.xml</urn:DocumentSystemFileNm>
</urn:ACATransmitterManifestReqDtl>
<urn2:ACABusinessHeader wsu:Id="id-FBA20BF181754306AAEF7C0E86D921CF">
<urn:UniqueTransmissionId>32BIRD31-2615-3DD5-D053-6AD4570A4735:SYS12:<ID>::T</urn:UniqueTransmissionId>
<urn1:Timestamp>2016-05-18T00:28:01Z</urn1:Timestamp>
</urn2:ACABusinessHeader>
<urn3:ACASecurityHeader/>
<wsa:Action>BulkRequestTransmitter</wsa:Action>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include">
<urn4:ACABulkRequestTransmitter version="1.0">
<urn1:BulkExchangeFile>
<xop:Include href="cid:1094B_Request_<ID>_20160513T090758000Z.xml"/>
</urn1:BulkExchangeFile>
</urn4:ACABulkRequestTransmitter>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
------=_Part_1_417037542.1463661950204
Content-Type: application/xml;name=1094B_Request_<ID>_20160513T090758000Z.xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment;name=1094B_Request_<ID>_20160513T090758000Z.xml
Content-ID: 1094B_Request_<ID>_20160513T090758000Z.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Form109495BTransmittalUpstream xmlns="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:form1094-1095Btransmitterupstreammessage" xmlns:common="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common" xmlns:xmlmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmlns:xsd="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:air="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0">
    <air:Form1094BUpstreamDetail recordType="String" lineNum="0">
        <air:SubmissionId>1</air:SubmissionId>
        <air:TestScenarioId>1-0</air:TestScenarioId>
        <common:TaxYr>2015</common:TaxYr>
        <air:BusinessName>
            <air:BusinessNameLine1Txt>Hidetestone</air:BusinessNameLine1Txt>
        </air:BusinessName>
        <common:TINRequestTypeCd>BUSINESS_TIN</common:TINRequestTypeCd>
        <common:EmployerEIN>343434343</common:EmployerEIN>
        <air:ContactNameGrp>
            <air:PersonFirstNm>Tharba</air:PersonFirstNm>
            <air:PersonLastNm>bengan</air:PersonLastNm>
        </air:ContactNameGrp>
        <air:ContactPhoneNum>44454545454</air:ContactPhoneNum>
        <air:MailingAddressGrp>
            <air:USAddressGrp>
                <air:AddressLine1Txt>87 Bouler Lane Suite 312</air:AddressLine1Txt>
                <common:CityNm>New York</common:CityNm>
                <air:USStateCd>NY</air:USStateCd>
                <common:USZIPCd>87990</common:USZIPCd>
            </air:USAddressGrp>
        </air:MailingAddressGrp>
        <air:Form1095BAttachedCnt>2</air:Form1095BAttachedCnt>
        <air:Form1095BUpstreamDetail recordType="String" lineNum="0">
            <air:RecordId>1</air:RecordId>
            <air:TestScenarioId>1-2</air:TestScenarioId>
            <air:CorrectedInd>0</air:CorrectedInd>
            <common:TaxYr>2015</common:TaxYr>
            <air:ResponsibleIndividualGrp>
                <air:ResponsibleIndividualName>
                    <air:PersonFirstNm>NAANA</air:PersonFirstNm>
                    <air:PersonLastNm>MART</air:PersonLastNm>
                </air:ResponsibleIndividualName>
                <common:TINRequestTypeCd>INDIVIDUAL_TIN</common:TINRequestTypeCd>
                <common:BirthDt>1973-02-06</common:BirthDt>
                <air:MailingAddressGrp>
                    <air:USAddressGrp>
                        <air:AddressLine1Txt>1313 THORN LANE</air:AddressLine1Txt>
                        <common:CityNm>GEORGIA</common:CityNm>
                        <air:USStateCd>DC</air:USStateCd>
                        <common:USZIPCd>90877</common:USZIPCd>
                    </air:USAddressGrp>
                </air:MailingAddressGrp>
                <air:PolicyOriginCd>D</air:PolicyOriginCd>
            </air:ResponsibleIndividualGrp>
            <air:IssuerInfoGrp>
                <air:BusinessName>
                    <air:BusinessNameLine1Txt>OITSAT</air:BusinessNameLine1Txt>
                </air:BusinessName>
                <common:TINRequestTypeCd>BUSINESS_TIN</common:TINRequestTypeCd>
                <common:EIN>34343434</common:EIN>
                <air:ContactPhoneNum>5551352468</air:ContactPhoneNum>
                <air:MailingAddressGrp>
                    <air:USAddressGrp>
                        <air:AddressLine1Txt>975 Blder Lane Suite 312</air:AddressLine1Txt>
                        <common:CityNm>New York</common:CityNm>
                        <air:USStateCd>OR</air:USStateCd>
                        <common:USZIPCd>98903</common:USZIPCd>
                    </air:USAddressGrp>
                </air:MailingAddressGrp>
            </air:IssuerInfoGrp>
            <air:CoveredIndividualGrp>
                <air:CoveredIndividualName>
                    <air:PersonFirstNm>LOLLY</air:PersonFirstNm>
                    <air:PersonLastNm>OIRS</air:PersonLastNm>
                </air:CoveredIndividualName>
                <common:BirthDt>1973-02-06</common:BirthDt>
                <air:CoveredIndividualAnnualInd>0</air:CoveredIndividualAnnualInd>
                <air:CoveredIndividualMonthlyIndGrp>
                    <air:JanuaryInd>0</air:JanuaryInd>
                    <air:FebruaryInd>0</air:FebruaryInd>
                    <air:MarchInd>0</air:MarchInd>
                    <air:AprilInd>0</air:AprilInd>
                    <air:MayInd>0</air:MayInd>
                    <air:JuneInd>1</air:JuneInd>
                    <air:JulyInd>1</air:JulyInd>
                    <air:AugustInd>1</air:AugustInd>
                    <air:SeptemberInd>1</air:SeptemberInd>
                    <air:OctoberInd>1</air:OctoberInd>
                    <air:NovemberInd>1</air:NovemberInd>
                    <air:DecemberInd>1</air:DecemberInd>
                </air:CoveredIndividualMonthlyIndGrp>
            </air:CoveredIndividualGrp>
            <air:CoveredIndividualGrp>
                <air:CoveredIndividualName>
                    <air:PersonFirstNm>WARD</air:PersonFirstNm>
                    <air:PersonLastNm>IUTS</air:PersonLastNm>
                </air:CoveredIndividualName>
                <common:SSN>000000120</common:SSN>
                <air:CoveredIndividualAnnualInd>0</air:CoveredIndividualAnnualInd>
                <air:CoveredIndividualMonthlyIndGrp>
                    <air:JanuaryInd>0</air:JanuaryInd>
                    <air:FebruaryInd>0</air:FebruaryInd>
                    <air:MarchInd>0</air:MarchInd>
                    <air:AprilInd>0</air:AprilInd>
                    <air:MayInd>0</air:MayInd>
                    <air:JuneInd>1</air:JuneInd>
                    <air:JulyInd>1</air:JulyInd>
                    <air:AugustInd>1</air:AugustInd>
                    <air:SeptemberInd>1</air:SeptemberInd>
                    <air:OctoberInd>1</air:OctoberInd>
                    <air:NovemberInd>1</air:NovemberInd>
                    <air:DecemberInd>1</air:DecemberInd>
                </air:CoveredIndividualMonthlyIndGrp>
            </air:CoveredIndividualGrp>
        </air:Form1095BUpstreamDetail>
        <air:Form1095BUpstreamDetail recordType="String" lineNum="0">
            <air:RecordId>2</air:RecordId>
            <air:TestScenarioId>1-1</air:TestScenarioId>
            <air:CorrectedInd>0</air:CorrectedInd>
            <common:TaxYr>2015</common:TaxYr>
            <air:ResponsibleIndividualGrp>
                <air:ResponsibleIndividualName>
                    <air:PersonFirstNm>NANNA</air:PersonFirstNm>
                    <air:PersonMiddleNm>WINNONA</air:PersonMiddleNm>
                    <air:PersonLastNm>NEG</air:PersonLastNm>
                </air:ResponsibleIndividualName>
                <common:TINRequestTypeCd>INDIVIDUAL_TIN</common:TINRequestTypeCd>
                <common:SSN>000000101</common:SSN>
                <air:MailingAddressGrp>
                    <air:USAddressGrp>
                        <air:AddressLine1Txt>4435 NUT AVENUE</air:AddressLine1Txt>
                        <common:CityNm>MADISON</common:CityNm>
                        <air:USStateCd>GA</air:USStateCd>
                        <common:USZIPCd>87940</common:USZIPCd>
                    </air:USAddressGrp>
                </air:MailingAddressGrp>
                <air:PolicyOriginCd>D</air:PolicyOriginCd>
            </air:ResponsibleIndividualGrp>
            <air:IssuerInfoGrp>
                <air:BusinessName>
                    <air:BusinessNameLine1Txt>Hidstone</air:BusinessNameLine1Txt>
                </air:BusinessName>
                <common:TINRequestTypeCd>BUSINESS_TIN</common:TINRequestTypeCd>
                <common:EIN>874995</common:EIN>
                <air:ContactPhoneNum>5551352468</air:ContactPhoneNum>
                <air:MailingAddressGrp>
                    <air:USAddressGrp>
                        <air:AddressLine1Txt>11 Bouder Lane Suite 312</air:AddressLine1Txt>
                        <common:CityNm>New York</common:CityNm>
                        <air:USStateCd>NY</air:USStateCd>
                        <common:USZIPCd>56656</common:USZIPCd>
                    </air:USAddressGrp>
                </air:MailingAddressGrp>
            </air:IssuerInfoGrp>
            <air:CoveredIndividualGrp>
                <air:CoveredIndividualName>
                    <air:PersonFirstNm>NANNA</air:PersonFirstNm>
                    <air:PersonMiddleNm>WINNONA</air:PersonMiddleNm>
                    <air:PersonLastNm>URTN</air:PersonLastNm>
                </air:CoveredIndividualName>
                <common:SSN>000000101</common:SSN>
                <air:CoveredIndividualAnnualInd>1</air:CoveredIndividualAnnualInd>
                <air:CoveredIndividualMonthlyIndGrp>
                    <air:JanuaryInd>0</air:JanuaryInd>
                    <air:FebruaryInd>0</air:FebruaryInd>
                    <air:MarchInd>0</air:MarchInd>
                    <air:AprilInd>0</air:AprilInd>
                    <air:MayInd>0</air:MayInd>
                    <air:JuneInd>0</air:JuneInd>
                    <air:JulyInd>0</air:JulyInd>
                    <air:AugustInd>0</air:AugustInd>
                    <air:SeptemberInd>0</air:SeptemberInd>
                    <air:OctoberInd>0</air:OctoberInd>
                    <air:NovemberInd>0</air:NovemberInd>
                    <air:DecemberInd>0</air:DecemberInd>
                </air:CoveredIndividualMonthlyIndGrp>
            </air:CoveredIndividualGrp>
            <air:CoveredIndividualGrp>
                <air:CoveredIndividualName>
                    <air:PersonFirstNm>ISAIAS</air:PersonFirstNm>
                    <air:PersonLastNm>UVERD</air:PersonLastNm>
                </air:CoveredIndividualName>
                <common:SSN>000000002</common:SSN>
                <air:CoveredIndividualAnnualInd>1</air:CoveredIndividualAnnualInd>
                <air:CoveredIndividualMonthlyIndGrp>
                    <air:JanuaryInd>0</air:JanuaryInd>
                    <air:FebruaryInd>0</air:FebruaryInd>
                    <air:MarchInd>0</air:MarchInd>
                    <air:AprilInd>0</air:AprilInd>
                    <air:MayInd>0</air:MayInd>
                    <air:JuneInd>0</air:JuneInd>
                    <air:JulyInd>0</air:JulyInd>
                    <air:AugustInd>0</air:AugustInd>
                    <air:SeptemberInd>0</air:SeptemberInd>
                    <air:OctoberInd>0</air:OctoberInd>
                    <air:NovemberInd>0</air:NovemberInd>
                    <air:DecemberInd>0</air:DecemberInd>
                </air:CoveredIndividualMonthlyIndGrp>
            </air:CoveredIndividualGrp>
        </air:Form1095BUpstreamDetail>
    </air:Form1094BUpstreamDetail>
</Form109495BTransmittalUpstream>

------=_Part_1_417037542.1463661950204--
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution after long struggle ,by doing below. Thank you every one for the hints and suggestions.

**HTTP Header ContentType :**
Content-Type should be as below, It should not just say multipart/related. Earlier I have missed to add boundary with unique ID. After adding boundary with unique id, I can see success.

Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; start="  "; start-info="text/xml"; boundary="------  =_Part_20_771186217.1464204801278"

**Multiple Carriage Returns:**
The SOAP Message which i built has two carriage returns between the last HTTP header (Expect: 100-continue) and the first message boundary. There should be only one to make it success.

**The Content-Type and Content-Transfer-Encoding headers for the MTOM attachment are incorrect:** They should be as shown below.

Content-Type: text/xml; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Comment: The above statements provided above are also correct for solutions using .NET.

Answer (score 0):

**wsa:Action** and **SOAPAction** should be **BulkRequestTransmitterService**.

Comment: Hi Abramyan, I have added wsa:Action as well as SOAPAction to BulkRequestTransmitterService..Still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I was getting TPE1105 on my status transmission also.  It wasn't a problem with the XML directly.  I sent the XML to my routine that applies the GZIP encoding.  I had an incorrect length specified, so it added NULL characters to the end.  Verify the actual length of the XML is what the GZIP routine is compressing.  I had to use Fiddler to capture the data as it was sent to the IRS.  Then I had it unzip it and I could see the NULLs after the closing tag.

Comment: Hi Clark, Thank you for response,As you recommended. I have tried verifying with Fiddler for extra null characters , I dont see any null characters.Still i see TPE1105

Answer (score 0):

TPE1105 is first level error that IRS checks. We faced this error while developing solution for IRS submission. Most likely cause is attachment content type. I have created a sample project for IRS submission. This is not production code and has some hard-coding, but, this can be seen as entry point for your solution

https://github.com/sangramjadhav/irsclient

For this, you need to configure certificate store path and other parameters.
Please see application.yml file and update accordingly if you want to try out

Comment: The project listed on GitHub does not appear to have a license.txt file.  Could you please clarify what license the source code falls under?

Comment: @nestharus Added License(MIT) to github repo.